# Android devices sends null data to PHP

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am new to Android, and I am developing an application with PHP and MySQL. I am trying to send some data to a PHP script from my device and add the data to my database, but the data added to the database is null. I am not working with the emulator, only with an Android device. Here is my PHP and Java code:

```
$dbHost = "localhost";
$dbName = "emergency_db";
$dbUser = "root";
$dbPassword = "";

$connect = mysql_connect($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPassword) or die ("Connection error"); // connects to database
mysql_select_db($dbName) or die ("Database selection error"); // selects the database

$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$name=$_POST['name'];
$email=$_POST['email'];

mysql_query("INSERT INTO USERS(Username, Password, Name, Email)VALUES('$username', '$password', '$name' , '$email')");

mysql_close($connect);
```

---

```
try {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost/register.php");
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(4);
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username ));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
}
```

Comment: Did you test the data you are trying to send for null values?

Comment: I have tested the data from the phone and they are not null..

Comment: I'm new to PHP, bt I guess you need to open Db connection

Comment: I assume the PHP isn't running on the phone itself? And therefore that you're not _really_ using `localhost` in the url in Android?

Comment: two things: 1) can you connect to database?, and 2) what does this string look like echoed out `"INSERT INTO USERS(Username, Password, Name, Email)VALUES('$username', '$password', '$name' , '$email')"`?

Comment: I think it connects correct to database otherwise it would not insert the null data to my table. Also, I echoed the query as a string and it shows: INSERT INTO USERS(Username, Password, Name, Email)VALUES('', '', '' , '')

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysqli` . Use of `mysql` is now deprecated.

You have to use `http://192.168.xxx.xxx/register.php` instead of `http://localhost/register.php` if you are testing it on common network .

Replace you `mysql_query` with this:

```
mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO test (name,age,email) VALUES ('$name', '$age', '$email');)";
```